# Docker plugin : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/main/docker/Dockerfile gradle-docker fails

Tags: docker, spring-boot, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

I'm trying to run [spring boot sample](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/) on osx (mbp) and I'm getting following exception (Trying buildDocker task). I'm sure I have configured docker properly as I can run command `docker-machine run hello-world` and receive proper output.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /src/main/docker/Dockerfile (No such file or directory)
    at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.image.Dockerfile.fromExternalFile(Dockerfile.groovy:45)
    at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.image.Dockerfile$fromExternalFile.call(Unknown Source)
    at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask.buildDockerfile(DockerTask.groovy:223)
    at se.transmode.gradle.plugins.docker.DockerTask.build(DockerTask.groovy:238)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    ... 54 more
```

Other validation would be I can run gradle-docker default build task (i.e. distDocker) without any problem. Problem occur when I try to run build following build task on the gradle script.

```
    // tag::task[]
task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: build) {
  push = true
  applicationName = jar.baseName
  dockerfile = file('/src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
  doFirst {
    copy {
      from jar
      into stageDir
    }
  }
}
// end::task[]
```

I can't workout why it cannot determine the file when it's already exists. I tried copying into root and change path for no luck.

OSX : 10.10.4
Java : 1.8

Comment: Which directory are you running the buildDocker? Are you using gradlew or gradle? What's your command? I run the same task from the project root ditectory as: ./gradlew buildDocker

Comment: @Bloodysock Running from dir /Users/charith/gs-spring-boot-docker/complete/ and using gradlew.

Comment: I use the same command ./gradlew --stacktrace buildDocker

Comment: Remove the '/' before src in the path. The path is relative from the current directory (project root) and not the volume root.

Comment: Thanks heaps mate, that was it. Solves the problem. I should have tried that before. cheers!

Comment: @Bloodysock, do you wanna post this as answer so that I can approve it? There could be more people like me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the '/' before src in the path. The path is relative from the current directory (project root) and not the volume root.